# Spring mvc validation working during new form but fail show validation when try to update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I have an input form write for both add & update user information purposes.
The same submit form can perform for add & update correctly, just problem raise if I try to purposely submit empty data/ wrong format, the validation can show message while try to add new user, but not on update user.
validation included `NotEmpty`/`Email`/`typeMismatch` etc...

Any help to allow show validation message in same form?
Why try to add can show, but not during update?
I just started SpringMVC, hope someone help.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
@ModelAttribute
public void getUserDetail(@RequestParam(value = "udId", required = false)  
    Integer udId,
    Map<String, Object> map) {

    //For update UserDetail form

    if (udId != null) {
        UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
        try {
            userDetail = userDetailService.getUserDetail(udId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("failed to get UserDetail with udId: " + udId);
        }
        map.put("userDetail", userDetail);
    }
}


//Add
@RequestMapping(value = "/userDetail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUserDetail(@Valid UserDetail userDetail,
    BindingResult bingdingResult) {

    if (bingdingResult.getErrorCount() > 0) {
        log.info("User attempt create user: " + userDetail.toString());
        for (FieldError error : bingdingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
            log.info(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        //redirect to same page to show error return infor (NotEmpty etc...)
        return "/user/inputUserDetail";
    } else {
        try {
            userDetailService.addUserDetail(userDetail);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to add new UserDetail: " + 
                     userDetail.toString());
        }
        return "redirect:/user/userDetails";
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/userDetail", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String updateUserDetail(@Valid UserDetail userDetail,
    BindingResult bingdingResult, Map<String, Object> map) {

    //Update - need UserDetail model attribute

    if (bingdingResult.getErrorCount() > 0) {
        log.info("User attempt update user: " + userDetail.toString());
        for (FieldError error : bingdingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
            log.info(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        // redirect to same page to show error return infor (NotEmpty etc...)
        // error cannot display error message
        return "/user/inputUserDetail";
    } else {
        try {
            //update user detail
            userDetailService.updateUserDetail(userDetail);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to update UserDetail: " +     
                   userDetail.toString());
        }
        return "redirect:/user/userDetails";
    }
}
```

Additional coding:

```
//Service layer:
@Service("userDetailHistoryService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class UserDetailHistoryServiceImpl implements UserDetailHistoryService{
    @Override
    public void updateUserDetailHistory(UserDetailHistory userDetailHistory) {
        userDetailHistoryDao.updateUserDetailHistory(userDetailHistory);
    }
    //other coding etc.. etc...
}

@Repository("userDetail")
public class UserDetailDaoImpl implements UserDetailDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    //Dao layer:
    @Override
    public void updateUserDetail(UserDetail userDetail) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(userDetail);
    }
    //other coding etc.. etc...
}
```

---

Welcome any suggestions and ideas? 
Thanks again.

Error occur when I try submit update to `NotEmpty` field, below attach long error message:

```
>Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.get(Collections.java:1454)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getEncodingForIndex(ConnectionImpl.java:2780)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Field.<init>(Field.java:185)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.unpackField(MysqlIO.java:723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:418)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3105)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2336)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2729)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1369)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings(SQLError.java:704)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings(SQLError.java:656)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.getWarnings(StatementImpl.java:2145)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.getWarnings(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1806)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.handleAndClearWarnings(SqlExceptionHelper.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logAndClearWarnings(SqlExceptionHelper.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:529)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.release(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:1012)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.permissiveInitialization(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.toString(UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.java)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.BodyMeasure.toString(BodyMeasure.java:220)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:317)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail.toString(UserDetail.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1366.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:196)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.toString(UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.java)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.BodyMeasure.toString(BodyMeasure.java:220)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:317)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail.toString(UserDetail.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1366.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:196)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.toString(UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.java)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.BodyMeasure.toString(BodyMeasure.java:220)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:317)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail.toString(UserDetail.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1366.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:196)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.toString(UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.java)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.BodyMeasure.toString(BodyMeasure.java:220)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:317)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail.toString(UserDetail.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1366.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:196)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.toString(UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.java)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.BodyMeasure.toString(BodyMeasure.java:220)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:317)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail.toString(UserDetail.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1366.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:196)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.toString(UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.java)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.BodyMeasure.toString(BodyMeasure.java:220)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:317)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail.toString(UserDetail.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1366.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:196)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.toString(UserDetail_$$_jvstb9a_8c.java)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.BodyMeasure.toString(BodyMeasure.java:220)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:317)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.faddistwardrobe.web.model.UserDetail.toString(UserDetail.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1366.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

etc....................................long message related to hibernate...

Comment: Seems like it is not a problem with Spring MVC, according to a stacktrace, after submission call passed to a service layer and falls somewhere in that part. Could you show the code of `userDetailService.updateUserDetail(userDetail);`? So if you expected error message on validation it is not shown by some other reason. Stacktrace related to another part of the code which already passed validation. Also, provide part of the stackstrace, which shows what line of you code cause exception (the very beginning of the stacktrace).

Comment: Service layer: 
    @Override
    public void updateUserDetailHistory(UserDetailHistory userDetailHistory) {
        userDetailHistoryDao.updateUserDetailHistory(userDetailHistory);
    }

Comment: DAO layer: 
    @Override
    public void updateUserDetail(UserDetail userDetail) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(userDetail);
    }

Comment: It is possible caused by hibernate?

Comment: Add the stackstrace part with original error to get an idea about the codeline that caused this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/new" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newEmployee(ModelMap model) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/new" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEmployee(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult result,
            ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }                   
        service.saveEmployee(employee);    
        return "success";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-{ssn}-employee" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editEmployee(@PathVariable String ssn, ModelMap model) {
        Employee employee = service.findEmployeeBySsn(ssn);
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        model.addAttribute("edit", true);
        return "registration";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-{ssn}-employee" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateEmployee(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult result,
            ModelMap model, @PathVariable String ssn) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }    

        service.updateEmployee(employee);     
        return "success";
    }
```